# Finding the orthogonal complement of a particular set

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\ell^2$ denote the vector space of all square summable sequences with the inner product defined as $\langle x,y\rangle = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i \bar y_i$, and $\ell_0$ denote the space of sequences that have finitely many non-zero terms. Given $y = (1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\dots)\in\ell^2$, define $A = \{x \in\ell_0\mid x \perp y\}$. How to find $A^\perp$?

Comment: What do you mean by $l_0$? That's a new one on me.

Comment: Is $l_0$ the set of the convergent sequences to zero ?

Comment: @CameronBuie I think $l_0$ is the space of bounded sequences.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: I've typically seen that denoted $\ell^\infty$, personally.

Comment: What does $x\perp y \in \ell^2$ mean?

Comment: @CameronBuie yeah same here. I can't think what else it could mean though. This question has a lot of issues with it. :/

Comment: @Mercy: That, I suspect, means that $x\perp y,$ when $x,y$ are considered as elements of $\ell^2$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Indeed.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, $l_0$ is the space of sequences which have finitely many non-zero terms.

Comment: @user77404 after looking up $L^0$ just now, I realized this is what you meant. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @user77404 what do you mean by $x\perp y\in l^2$?

Comment: I was just trying to say that the element y, is actually what I wrote in the question, which is a element of $l^2$

Comment: @user77404  What you meant isn't the same as what you wrote because $x\perp y$ is not an element and you already mentioned that $y \in \ell^2$

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, is the question more clear now after the edit?

Comment: I like this $\ell^n$ notation. I guess a sequence $(a_i)$ satisfies $(a_i)\in\ell^n$ if $\sum_i |a_i|^n < \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\ell_0 \subset \ell^2$, we have
$$
A=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n, 
$$
where
$$
A_n=\left\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n,0,\ldots)  :\ \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k}{k}=0\right\}.
$$
Obviously $A_1=0$ and $A_n=\text{span}\mathscr{B}_{n-1}\cong \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ for every $n \ge 2$, with 
$$
\mathscr{B}_{n-1}=\left\{e_1-2e_2,\ldots,e_1-ne_n\right\} ,
$$
where $\{e_i\}_i$ denotes the standard basis of $\ell^2$.

It follows that
\begin{eqnarray}
A^\perp&=&\{z \in \ell^2:\ z\perp A\}=\{z \in \ell^2: \ z\perp \mathscr{B}_{n-1} \forall n \ge 2\}\\
&=&\{z \in \ell^2: z_1-nz_n=0 \quad \forall n \ge 2\}=\mathbb{R}y.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Since (x,y) = 0 that obviously implies that for any $ c \in R$ that $c(x,y) = 0, (cx,y) = 0$.

Comment: I just realized that the way you defined $A^{\perp}$ might not be correct, because in $A^{\perp}$ we should have $z \in l_0$ not that $z \in l^2$ like you defined it?

Comment: Why should it be $z \in \ell_0$? I suggest that you check the definition of the orthogonal complement! See, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement

Comment: I thought in this question we are defining the vector space to be $l_0$. Let me review the orthogonal complement definition again and look back at this.